# Linq select Objects from List which have empty String

Tags: c#, linq

is it possible in Linq to select from IEnumerable of this object

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

where Type is "" ?

if I loop over the list with that

```
        foreach (Foo f in dataFoos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.Id + f.Type);
        }
```

it looks like

1one

2

3three

I have tried

```
var emptyType0 = dataFoos.Where(f => f.Type.Length <= 1);
var emptyType1 = dataFoos.Where(f => f.Type == null || f.Type == "");
```

both did not return any result. Any hint on how to properly check if String values are empty ?

if I do that

```
        var df = dataFoos.Where(f => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.Type));

        foreach (Foo f in df)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.Id + f.Type);
        }
        var df1 = dataFoos.Where(f => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.Type));

        foreach (Foo f in df1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.Id + f.Type);
        }
```

the second loop does not return any value

I am using dotnetcore c#. Thanks for any hint

Comment: Your code should work. Show how you populate your `foos` variable.

Comment: I have added some loop output. Still the linq queries are empty

Comment: If any object have `f.Type = null` then your first `Where(f => f.Type.Length <= 1)` will throw exception. Moreover it should be `< 1` not `<= 1`. Your second condition is perfect but what if your `Type` has value with `spaces ("   ")` then it will not return those. You can use `var emptyType1 = foos.Where(f => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.Type));` or use `Trim()` as `var emptyType1 = foos.Where(f => f.Type == null || f.Type.Trim() == "");`

Comment: @user3732793: Are you sure that your second entry is acutally empty? Or does it have some whitespace character like space or tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should cover almost every type of null/blank/just whitespace

```
var emptyType1 = foos.Where(f => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.Type));
```

but more likely what you want to do is *exclude* those - not *include* them

```
var dataFoos = foos.Where(f => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.Type));

foreach (Foo f in dataFoos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(f.Id + f.Type);
}
```

Comment: Side note: Any styling reason why you use `String` instead of `string`?

Comment: @Magnetron it's the same thing. One is just an alias of the other

Comment: @Jamiec that did work but than foos is empty I would hope I can generate other Lists too from foo !?

Comment: @user3732793 I'm afraid I don't understand. What other list do you want to generate?

Comment: @Jamiec Yeah, I know, that's why I put the _styling reason_. It's just that I usually see, and VS recommend, the alias version. So I just got curious if you have a specific reason to prefer one over the other.

Comment: @Magnetron habit only I guess. `string` is the c# type so I use that for defining params/vars etc. `String` has static methods like `IsNullOr....`. I know you can use either interchangably but it's just my personal taste

Comment: @Jamiec at least two Lists one with Type set and one with no type set. If  I use your example it only works once.

Comment: @user3732793 you can do it as many times as you like as long as you go to the original source. In this answer, `emptyTypes1` will be an enumeration (not a list!) of ones without type set and `dataFoos` would have ones with type set.

Comment: @Jamiec thought so too. I have added the your loop example with the comment that second time it is empty. When debugging even the second time accessing dataFoo it is empty

Comment: @user3732793 ahh I think I understand. `dataFoos` is an enumerable, not a list. Once you've enumerated to the end of it thats it. If you want to convert it to a list use `ToList()`

Comment: you are the man ! that did the trick. I did not now that about the enumartion once pitfall.